# How to show month name in Crystal report chart?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am using Crystal Report 2008, in Line Chart I want to show month name like Jan Feb March on x-Axes in report. How do I show months on x-Axes?

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this is create a separate formula field with the following formula

```
cstr(monthname(month({YourDateFieldHere})))
```

Use this in your chart.

This simply pulls the month from the date here. If you require to change this any, I'm sure you can change the format by right clicking, or alternatively if it shows up 01, 02, 03 ect.. you could use a series of IF statements in your formula, for example

```
IF {YourDateFORMULA} = "01" THEN January
```

And so on, although this shouldn't be needed as the MonthName function in the original formula should cover this.

Comment: How can I display the month name in another language?

Comment: I think this would be best asked as a new question.

Comment: @ParanoidAndroid apparently I must have downvoted by mistake, unfortunately it won't let me change it now. Apologies, definitely unintentional