# Display Month Name Instead of Month Number In Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

How Can I display Month Name Instead of Month Number (Not Data Format Number) In Crystal Report?

Comment: Use `MonthName`, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402502/how-to-show-month-name-in-crystal-report-chart).

Answer (score 15):

The `MonthName` function can be used to display the name of the month, when you provide a number between 1 and 12 (1 being January). It is useful for showing the month name in Group titles or labeling groups in charts.

It can be combined with the DatePart function to return the month name of a variable or calculation.

**Syntax**

```
 MonthName(month, abbr) 

    Month   A number from 1 to 12.    
    abbr    Optional.A Boolean value. If true, the month name is abbreviated. The default is false.
```

**Examples**

```
Example                                 Result
MonthName(5)                            “May”
MonthName(10)                           “October”
MonthName(10,True)                      “Oct”
MonthName(DatePart(“m”, CurrentDate))   “October” when the current date is 10/5/10.
```

Comment: Was helpful to see the syntax for month abbreviations too

Comment: I have date and month in format yyyyMM with int feild, I have added this formula to show month name and year
MonthName(ToNumber(Right(totext({FeeRecordCharges.Month},0,''),2))) + ' ' + Left(totext({FeeRecordCharges.Month},0,''),4)